# need help running chmod as part of a bash file. Documentation included

Tags: bash, debugging, sh, chmod, bash-completion

Ok so I want to write a bashfile system that tells a larger program that a file outputs this error message from chmod.

```
bash: ./\[bashfile-name\].sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

---

Here's the relevant part of the code, format is bashfile.

```
error=$(chmod +x $fdnm 2\>&1 \> /dev/null)

echo "value for error was "$error

if \[ $error = "bash "$filename": /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory" ]  
^^this is line 24^^

then 
   echo "patch would be done"


else
   echo "the file appears to be executable."
fi
```

---

Got this as output

```
value for error was chmod: cannot access '/media/usb/run-bi.sh'$'\r': No such file or directory
the file appears to be executable.
```

---

with these errors

```
./bad-interpreter.sh: line 24: [: too many arguments
chmod: missing operand after ‘+x’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
```

please debug. Thank you all.

Comment: `$'\r'` is how bash writes a carriage return. In DOS and Windows tools, lines are ended with CRLF sequences (aka `\r\n`); in UNIX tools, it should be only a LF with no CR.

Comment: $fdnm is a variable that contains something like /fileaddress/bashfile.sh

Comment: Use `dos2unix` to convert your script to UNIX form.

Comment: Also, `2>&1` should just be `2>&1`, no backslashes. Consider running your script through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: the problem is that `fdnm` contains not only the filename, but also a carriage return at the end of that filename; that's the `\r` the error is talking about.

Comment: (as a separate matter, `if [ $error = "..." ]` should be `if [ "$error" = "..." ]` -- you need to quote your parameter expansions, not just strings).

Comment: I run 'fdnm=/media/usb/run-bi.sh' to dec.are the fdnm variable.

Comment: Yes, but if you run that in a file saved with DOS newlines it gets a CR on the end. The fixes in the linked duplicate will work; so will the `dos2unix` program I suggested 25 minutes ago.